# Matchit R - how to run ratio of 1 CONTROL: 2 TREATED units?

Tags: r, statistics, match, matching

Matchit R - how to run ratio of 1 CONTROL: 2 TREATED units? (20 CONTROLS FOR 40 TREATED SUBJECTS)
Ratio = for methods that allow it, how many control units should be matched to each treated unit in k:1 matching.
0.5 IS IMPOSSIBLE
how can I apply it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible because it doesn't make sense. Your question implies that treated units can be paired, but that presupposes a prior step in which treated units are matched with each other, which is not part of what `MatchIt` is designed to do (and doesn't really make sense from an experimental design standpoint anyway).

Either that, or you have pairs of treated cases that match exactly, in which case you're not really gaining any analytical leverage by trying to use them both. If that's the case, I would just reduce the pairs to single observation and go with 1:1 matching.

Comment: thanks, my treated units are not paired. but I want to have a sample of 20 controls for 40 treated units. Maybe I can sample 20 treated units (from my sample of 40 treated units), and then run 1:1 match?

Comment: Or maybe someone knows other python/R package to run ratio of 2 treated unit : 1 control?

Comment: Downsampling the treated units sounds like it might work. If you only have 20 control units available, though, it probably makes more sense to forget about matching; just include all 60 units; and try to address potential confounders in your model.

Comment: I have 120 optional control untis, I want to select the best 20 who match to my 40 treated units.

Comment: That just doesn't make any sense to me. What would make them the best? Being most like the treated units. So, then, why not do 1:1 or 2:1 matching by nearest neighbor?

Comment: We don’t have budget to run the experiment using a bigger control group, 
So we have to select the best 20 (out of 120 optional controls) who matched to our 40 treated units.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a much a harder question than it may seem. There is definitely no way to do this with nearest neighbor matching. In theory, it should be possible with optimal matching, e.g., using `method = "full"` or the `optmatch` package directly. Unfortunately, in my experiments, I am unable to get `optmatch` to do what you want. Ideally, you should be able to run

```
fullmatch(., min.controls = 1/2, max.controls = 1/2, mean.controls = 1/2)
```

but that doesn't actually produce the desired results. Maybe you can contact the `opmatch` authors with this problem, as it's an interesting one that their package should be able to solve.

There is another method you can use called cardinality matching, which will implemented in the next release of `MatchIt` but can be accessed in the development version using `devtools::install_github("ngreifer/MatchIt")`. Cardinality matching uses optimzation to select a subset of units that satisfy a sample size constraint and balance constraints set by the user. In this case, your sample size constraint is that the number of treated units is twice the number of control units. You need to set balance constraints, which are the maximum imbalance (in standardized mean difference units) allowable between the treated and control groups. If `A` is your treatment variable and `X1` and `X2` are the variables you are trying to match on, you could run the following code:

```
m <- matchit(A ~ X1 + X2, dataa = data, method = "cardinality", 
             estimand = "ATC", ratio = 2, tols = .01)
```

If a solution is possible, it will be produced. If not, you will have to relax the tolerance (i.e., increase `tols`) until it is. You can the run

```
summary(m, un = FALSE)
```

which will produce a summary of balance and the remaining sample size. If not all of your treated units are matched, then continue to increase `tols` until they are.

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't find the method 'cardinality', even though I installed it from Git. can you please send me a link to this method in git? thanks again

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't available before but is now.

Comment: I got thie comment: 'Warning message:
The optimizer failed to find an optimal solution in the time alotted. The returned solution may not be optimal.' but the mathces seems great (mean dif, etc. )

Comment: Yes, that is explained in the help file `?method_cardinality`. Glad it worked for you.